# Error 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to create a login form using angular-material. I am using `@angular/material": "^7.3.0`.

In `app.module.ts` i have imported the following and placed them in the imports array as well,

```
import {
  MatToolbarModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule,
  MatOptionModule, MatSelectModule, MatIconModule, 
  MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatTableModule,
  MatDividerModule, MatSnackBarModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

In `message.components.ts` i have the following

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']
})

export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MessageComponent>, 
               @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
          }
          public closeMe() {
            this.dialogRef.close();
          }
          ngOnInit() {
          }
        }
```

In my template message.component.html i have,

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Message</h1>
<mat-dialog-content> </mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="closeMe()">Close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I am getting the errors for mat-dialog-actions & mat-dialog-content,

```
'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element:
'mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element:
```

As per the documentation [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) both directives are available. What could be wrong in the code ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to import the `MatDialogModule` into your `AppModule` (at least I don't see it in the list of imports provided).
For future reference, the first line of the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) documentation tab will tell you the module(s) you need to import.

Comment: Oddly enough, I am getting this same error even with MatDialogModule in my imports

Comment: I had the same problem and realized that although I **was** importing the `MatDialogModule`, I  forgot to also declare my Dialog Component in my module.

Comment: I'm getting this error even though matdialogModule is imported into a sub-module, and it has been in use with another component in the project for some time. Have also imported and added MyComponent to the module declaration array.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets thanks :D you saved me hours !

Comment: This can also happen if you forgot to add the component in question to `declarations` in `@NgModule`.

Comment: as what previous comments have mentioned, add the dialog component to the `declarations` in `@NgModule`. since the dialog component is not created by the `ng generate` command, it's not automatically added to the `declarations` in `@NgModule`. so be sure to do that manually. it's a basic thing in angular but if you're like me who forgets that, i hope this comment helps you.

Answer (score 12):

I Agree with Jonathan Answer I am adding full details with example with sample code:

it will also resolve issues with error: **mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element**

Add DataDialogComponent in the declarations, and in entryComponents of app.module.ts

```
 import {MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';


   @NgModule({
    declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       MatDialogModule
    ],
    imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       AppRoutingModule,
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
       LayoutModule,

    ],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents:[MatDialogModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Since v9.0.0 `entryComponents` is no longer necessary.

Comment: In the `declarations` you must put the name of the exported class (which is `MessageComponent` btw) instead of `MatDialogModule`.

Answer (score 6):

For me, I forgot to register the dialog component in the same Module which import `MatDialogModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //..
    DeleteConfirmDialog,  // << register your dialog component Here
  ],
  imports: [
    //..
    // material
    MatDialogModule // << also dont't forget this 
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 4):

First,
You need to make sure that imported the `MatDialogModule` into your `AppModule`.

You can do both:

```
<div mat-dialog-content></div>
<div mat-dialog-actions></div>
```

Or

```
<mat-dialog-content></mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions></mat-dialog-actions>
```

If you look at the source of components/src/material/dialog/dialog-module.ts in Angular Materials git [repo](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog-module.ts), it exports the following directives.

```
import {
  MatDialogActions,
  MatDialogClose,
  MatDialogContent,
  MatDialogTitle,
} from './dialog-content-directives';

exports: [
    ...
    MatDialogClose,
    MatDialogTitle,
    MatDialogContent,
    MatDialogActions,
    ...
  ]
```

and with following similar declaration for each directive in ~/dialog-content-directives.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: `[mat-dialog-content], mat-dialog-content, [matDialogContent]`,
  host: {'class': 'mat-dialog-content'}
})
export class MatDialogContent {}
```

**If the problem persists, then try the following**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then run your project again.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was caused because I had not yet added my module that used the dialog into the routes of a parent module. (I am lazily loading using import())

So effectively, this module was not net a part of the angular app, because it had not yet been imported by any other modules of the app.

Comment: Yes, this can be one of reasons for this issue

Answer (score 2):

I've added 'MatDialogModule' to **app.module.ts** import, then the dialog component I've created to **app.module.ts** declarations !! This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar error when I was refactoring code.

The issue was because of duplicate component (copy pasted my dialog in 2 places). I renamed new one to a different name, and the issue is gone

```
ERROR in src/app/components/blah/result-dialog.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-dialog-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-dialog-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2 <mat-dialog-content >
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

@Brandon I am not sure if you resolved this, just listing out my findings.
Even I was facing same error issue even after importing  `MatDialogModule` , I eventually found out that we also need to import below, looks like **it was not throwing exact error**
 `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';`

Answer (score 0):

After updating from Angular 7 to 11 there is now not only *app.module.ts* but also a *componentname.module.ts* in every component.

I had to import MatDialogModule (and MatButtonModule for nicer looking buttons) there!