# angular dialog box did not work with material dialog content

Tags: angular

application dialog box is not working. because of error said 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element'

this is my module file content,

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ExtendDetailsComponent } from '../extend-details/extend-details.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ExtendDetailsComponent],
  entryComponents: [ExtendDetailsComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule, MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, MatDialogModule
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
})
export class ExtendDetailsModule { }
```

this is my html file

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Reject Confirmation <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" mat-button
    mat-dialog-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button> </h2>
```

my component file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-extend-details',
  templateUrl: 'extend-details.component.html',
 
})
export class ExtendDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

please check the below error. this is the issue.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576034/error-mat-dialog-content-is-not-a-known-element)

Comment: in my project, each component have module file. not from the app module

Comment: Can you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)?